# Adversary's advantages against mode of operation instantiated with random permutation and block cipher relation

Tags: block-cipher, provable-security, information-theory

I'm reading an article ["A Tweakable Enciphering Mode"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/148.pdf) by Halevi and Rogavay and wondering about one statement. On page 6 there are 3 inequalities:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \mathbf{Adv}_{\mathbb{CMC}[\text{Perm}(n)]}^{\pm\text{prp}}(n\sigma) & \leq
        \frac{5 \sigma ^ 2}{2 ^ n} \\
    \mathbf{Adv}_{\text{CMC}[\text{Perm}(n)]}^{\pm\widetilde{\text{prp}}}(n\sigma) & \leq
        \frac{7 \sigma ^ 2}{2 ^ n} \\
    \mathbf{Adv}_{\text{CMC}[E]}^{\pm\widetilde{\text{prp}}}(t, n\sigma) & \leq 
        \frac{7 \sigma ^ 2}{2 ^ n} + 2 \cdot \mathbf{Adv}_{E}^{\pm\text{prp}}(t', 2\sigma)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Right below these inequalities there are the following words about the last one:

> Equation (3) embodies the standard way to pass
> from the information-theoretic setting to the complexity-theoretic one

I've looked at the previous article about "buggy" EMD mode, which was superseeded with CMC described in the mentioned article, but there was almost the same text about this transition from advantage against mode of operation instantiated with a random permutation ($\text{Perm}(n)$) to advantage against the same mode of operation instantiated with a block cipher ($E$).

The question is: what is this "standard way"? How can I infer an advantage against block cipher in a mode of operation from a given advantage against random permutation in this mode? Is there any theorem, that gives a relation between these advantages? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any such theorem.

I seems to be based on indistinguishability of block cipher from a random permutation, but I can't figure out how.

Well, I there is such a theorem, so will it work in a slightly different setting, where I consider only a permutation, but not permutation and its inverse (i.e. with models without $\pm$)?

Comment: There are some useful thoughts in corollaries 5.21 and 5.22 from "Introduction to Modern Cryptography" by Bellare and Rogaway (May 11, 2005). It is actually almost the same transition, but for randomized CTR mode in IND-CPA model.